# Start touch and finish touch event Delphi

Tags: delphi, touch, firemonkey

I implement simple painting application in Delphi FMX for Windows pc with touch screen.

I am looking for a function which is invoked directly after the first touch on the screen and similar function invoked after finishing the touch. Very close to **MouseDown** and **MouseUp** and using **TControl.Pressed**.

I tried to use mouse functions but unfortunately, many windows touch screens do not send this event after touching the screen (some of them do).

I also tried **Tap** function but it is called only if you do not drag a finger over the screen.

Finally, I wanted to use **TGestureManager** but it seems to focus on just Gestures like zoom, rotate, etc.

Is there any other option to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

Use Gesture manager and catch **Pan** gesture (select it from Interactive gestures section in Object Inspector). Then you can get all details about gesture, detect direction and speed. Pan gesture return data at once after user started to swipe with finger.

Here is an example from my code:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormGesture(Sender: TObject; const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo;
  var Handled: Boolean);

var
  lTouchDirection: TTouchDirection;

  procedure GestureBegin;
  begin
    fGestureHandled := false;
    fSlideStartPos := EventInfo.Location;
  end;

  procedure GestureContinue;
  var
    dX, dY: Single;
  begin
    if fGestureHandled then exit;

    dX := EventInfo.Location.X - fSlideStartPos.X;
    dY := EventInfo.Location.Y - fSlideStartPos.Y;

    if (Abs(dX) < 1) and (Abs(dY) < 1) then  Exit;
    if lTouchDirection = TTouchDirection.tdNone then
    begin
      if Abs(dX) > Abs(dY) then
      begin  // horizontal
        if dX > 0 then
          lTouchDirection := TTouchDirection.tdRight
        else
          lTouchDirection := TTouchDirection.tdLeft;
      end
      else // vertical
      begin
        if dY > 0 then
          lTouchDirection := TTouchDirection.tdDown
        else
          lTouchDirection := TTouchDirection.tdUp;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure GestureEnd;
  begin
    fGestureHandled := false;
  end;

begin
  Handled := true;
  if Touch.InteractiveGestures = [] then exit;
  lTouchDirection := TTouchDirection.tdNone;

  if EventInfo.Flags = [TInteractiveGestureFlag.gfBegin] then
    GestureBegin;

  if EventInfo.Flags = [] then
    GestureContinue;

  if EventInfo.Flags = [TInteractiveGestureFlag.gfEnd] then
    GestureEnd;


end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the **MouseDown** events were sent but the **Pressed** property of TControl in FMX returns false even if you are touching the screen. The Pressed property reads only the mouse buttons down. After implementing **myPressed** property by **MouseDown** and **MouseUp**, myPressed was returning true even if you touch the screen and then remove the touch.

Comment: So, has your question been solved or not? It isn't clear from the answer here.

Comment: Can you kindly edit your answer to add a little more clarity? It doesn't look like you are clear on what you're saying in your answer.